# When is the orientation presheaf a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, orientation

The orientation presheaf of a topological $n$-manifold $X$ is 
$$U \mapsto H_n(X, X-U)$$

The manifold $X$ is orientable iff there exists a global section which is a generator of each stalk (I believe).

How is this related to the condition that the orientation presheaf be a sheaf? What does it mean morally for the orientation presheaf to be a sheaf? (I'm not asking for a restatement of the definition...I'm comfortable with that.)

Comment: I thought it was always a sheaf, a locally constant one, the sheaf of sections of the 2-sheeted cover of orientations of the manifold, and that the question is whether it is actually constant or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the excision theorem, you can check the sheaf property on a neighborhood of a point homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, in which case it is trivial using the covering space of $R$-orientations of a topological manifold (where $R$ is a general commutative unital ring ; in our case, use $R = \mathbb Z$). A very detailed explanation of the construction of this two-sheeted cover can be found in Hatcher, page 234-235. On $\mathbb R^n$, this covering space is trivial, i.e. equal to $X \times \mathbb Z$, which is to be expected since $\mathbb R^n$ is orientable, hence $\mathbb Z$-orientable. Translating the language of covering spaces into the language of sheaves, one must realize that an element $\sigma \in H_n(X,X \setminus U)$ is the same as a section $\sigma : U \to U_{\mathbb Z}$ where $\sigma(x)$ generates the $\mathbb Z$-module $H_n(X|x) = H_n(X, X \setminus \{x\})$ (using the language of Hatcher), since points in $U_{\mathbb Z}$ are stalks of the sheaf $(-) \mapsto H_n(X,X \setminus (-))$. Therefore, saying that the associated covering space is trivial ($\simeq X \times \mathbb Z$) is the same as saying that the sheaf is free of rank $1$. This gives locally freeness, hence $U \mapsto H_n(X,X \setminus U)$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$.

Now that you have locally freeness, the orientability question becomes obvious ; an orientation is an element $\sigma \in H_n(X) = H_n(X,X \setminus X)$ such that the corresponding element $\sigma_x \in H_n(X,X\setminus \{x\})$ is a generator of that $\mathbb Z$-module. Translating in the language of covering spaces, this is a global section of the covering map $\pi_X : X_{\mathbb Z} \to X$, say $\sigma : X \to X_{\mathbb Z}$ such that $\sigma_x$ generates the $\mathbb Z$-module $\pi_X^{-1}(\{x\})$. Translating in the language of sheaves, this amounts to saying that the orientation sheaf is free sheaf of abelian groups of rank $1$, i.e. the constant sheaf equal to $\mathbb Z$. (The translation is not necessary, but I feel it is helpful to see a section as an actual section of a projection map, which gives a good sense of the word "section".)

To read about the details, I guess Hatcher does a pretty good job of explaining how the maps work but it doesn't mention sheaves. If you know of a good book detailing the use of sheaves in algebraic topology, I'd love to hear your comments on that ; the only one I know is S. Ramanan's Global Calculus, which in my opinion contains a lot of good ideas but is (a tiny bit) sketchy in its presentation.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I totally agree about Ramanan. I'm a little ways into it and I believe I found one proof that's incorrect. But I do like the idea of the book at lot.

Comment: @EricAuld : An instance of a statement which is wrong in that book is that Theorem 4.14 is missing the hypothesis "$X$ is hereditarily paracompact", which is assumed when he quotes Example 1.10, 2). This is very annoying and makes me lose faith in all the statements I don't read thoroughly in this book. I even asked a question on this site because that assumption wasn't there.

Comment: I think that's exactly the one I'm talking about, and I believe I came across your question when I had the very same question.

Comment: Can you explain how you do the reduction with excision? I think compactness of X is a key assumption (see my "answer" below), and that is a property that can't be checked in a neighborhood of a point.

Comment: Your space in your example is not connected. Compactness is not what you want anyway in this context since you want to be able to work with arbitrary topological $n$-manifolds by looking at the connected components ; it becomes useful when looking for an orientation (i.e. a global section of this sheaf) or for Poincare duality.

Comment: Note that in your example, your presheaf restricted to each of the components is indeed a sheaf (trivially!). It should be obvious that by asking orientability questions, you would want connectedness ; if you have two distinct blobs, you are free to orient one blob independently of the other (since they are not "connected" to one another). Can you deal with the connected case with my explanations in my answer?

Comment: There's a book called "Sheaves in Topology" by Dimca that I'm planning to look at, in response to your question.

Answer (score 4):

It is always a sheaf, as it is the sheaf of sections of a surjective map, the covering map from the canonical double cover.

Comment: But you need the manifold to be compact, right? (Or else are you using Borel-Moore homology?)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important that $X$ is compact.

Otherwise, we can let $X = \mathbb{N}$, with the discrete topology. Call your presheaf $F$, so $F(U) = H_n(X, X \setminus U)$. Then $F(X) = H_n(X, X \setminus X) = \oplus_{X} \mathbb{Z}$. However, $F(x_i) = H_n(X,X \setminus x_i) = \mathbb{Z}$, so if we could glue then we would get global sections to be $F(X) = F(\bigcup x_i) = \Pi F(x_i) = \Pi_{\mathbb{X}} \mathbb{Z}$.

Of course, you can make similar counter examples in different dimensions, e.g. by taking a countable disjoint union of spheres.

Another example is $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself. This is orientable (in the sense of having a way to choose locally consistent generators of $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n \setminus x)$), so the stalkwise sheafification has $\mathbb{Z}$ global sections. But $F(\mathbb{R}^n) = H_n(\mathbb{R}^n, \emptyset) = 0$. If $F$ was a sheaf, it would be isomorphic to its sheafification; but this cannot be, because their global sections have different ranks.

I guess the point is that $H_n(X)$ is an inherently compact thing, since chains always have compact support.

I guess the other answers are correct provided one has the compactness assumption. I don't know, maybe I'm totally wrong. Maybe everyone is implicitely thinking of Borel-Moore homology?