Is the orientation presheaf always a sheaf?
I have the following definition for the orientation presheaf on a topological space $X$:
It's the fuctor $U \mapsto H_n(X,X \smallsetminus U)$, and with restriction maps the maps induced in relative homology by the inclusion of pairs; that is, if $V \subseteq U$ are open in $X$ then we have $(X,X\smallsetminus U) \hookrightarrow (X,X\smallsetminus V)$ which then induces a map $i_* \colon H_n(X,X\smallsetminus U) \rightarrow H_n(X,X\smallsetminus V)$.
These define a presheaf on X by functoriality of homology groups. First of all, I'd like to ask if this is the correct definition for the orientation (pre ?)sheaf. If this is the case, then my second question is whether this presheaf is always a sheaf. Actually my main concern is to understand if this is a sheaf when X is a topological variety of dimension $n$.
I'd also like to ask if there is a reference where I could study this.

Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1902034/when-is-the-orientation-presheaf-a-sheaf help?

I saw that post while looking into this, but it left me a bit unsatisfied as it seems to subsume the sheaf-theoretic aspect in the double covering one. I was wondering if one could avoid this and work directly with sheaves.

Some define this presheaf rather differently. For a topological $n$-manifold Iversen defines the orientation presheaf over a field $k$ to be $\mathrm{or}_X(U):=\mathscr{H}^n_C(U;\underline{k})^{\vee}$ with restriction maps being the $k$-linear duals of the 'extension by zero' morphism. By fancy stuff with Verdier duality, it turns out to be a sheaf (specifically when $k$ is a field; I'm not sure if the proof would generalise). And, that cohomology group is a sheaf cohomology group (surely this would equal the compactly supported singular cohomology here, but I don't know a proof of it)

This defines a reasonable presheaf. Now, consider the $1$-dimensional manifold $\mathbb{R}$ and denote the orientation presheaf by $\mathcal{F}$. The open sets $(-n,n),\,n>0$ form an increasing sequence that covers $\mathbb{R}$ and we have $\mathcal{F}((-n,n))=H_1(\mathbb{R},(-\infty,-n]\cup[n,\infty))=\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n>0$, compatible with the maps induced by the inclusions. Thus, the sections $s_n\in\mathcal{F}((-n,n))$ corresponding to $1\in\mathbb{Z}$ are compatible, so if this presheaf satisfied the gluing axiom, there would be a section $s\in\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})$ restricting to these, but $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})=H_1(\mathbb{R})=0$.
I think it's probably a sheaf for compact manifolds, but the argument escapes me right now...
